# How to set QWidget background color?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

The line `w.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Base)` in the code below has no effect. Why? How do I fix that?

```
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QWidget()
w.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Base)
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need to call `setAutoFillBackground(True)` on the widget. By default, a `QWidget` doesn't fill its background.

For more information, see the documentation for the [`setAutoFillBackground`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#autoFillBackground-prop) property.

If you want to use an arbitrary background color, you need to modify the widget's palette instead:

```
p = w.palette()
p.setColor(w.backgroundRole(), Qt.red)
w.setPalette(p)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Thanks for answering both the "why" and the "how"!

Comment: No problem. I should add that the Qt documentation is a bit unclear: the `QPalette::Window` role is used to fill a widget's background if it is a top-level window. Otherwise, your widget's `backgroundRole` is used instead, so your code should work as expected.

Comment: so its self.widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)

Comment: Hi, for me this have no effect while the answer of @Mohammad Nazari bellow works. Do you have an idea of what could be the reason?

Answer (score 9):

you can also use `setStyleSheet` for example:

```
w.setAttribute(Qt.Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
w.setStyleSheet('background-color: red;')
```