# Background type and color doesn´t work in Qt

Tags: qt, background, background-color, qtstylesheets

I have a widget which background is not transparent but gray as you can see in this image:

[image: The gray zone. Its set to white, but still appears gray]

I have a custom widget with a layout and this `ScrollArea` inside with this style:

```
background-color: white;
margin: 5px;  /*so it appears with 5 px around. the scroll bar is separated then*/
padding: 0px;
```

Inside a generic `QWidget` for the viewport to see (setWidget) with this style:

```
background: transparent;  // <---- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
```

If i try a color and not transparent, it doesn´t work. Always gray.
I also tried setAutoFillBackground(true) but didn´t work. (doesn´t work, anyway with styles).

The code for those two containers is this:

```
cameraModeParametersPanel_ = new QScrollArea();
(...)
cameraModeParametersPanel_->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
cameraModeParametersPanel_->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);
cameraModeParametersPanel_->setWidgetResizable(true);

mainParametersLayout->addWidget( cameraModeParametersPanel_ );  // the panel


QWidget* paramPanelViewportWidget = new QWidget();
(...)

QVBoxLayout* mainCameraLayout = new QVBoxLayout(paramPanelViewportWidget);
(...)
// and then i add QGroupBoxes with titles.
```

Comment: So what is the problem with one sentence?

Comment: It´s there. " My problem is that... no matter how many white backgrounds i set, or transparent, the background for the QWidget is always soft gray."

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set QWidget background color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655538/how-to-set-qwidget-background-color)

Comment: Nope! Obviously that´s not the answer. I tried both approaches before. Why would i ask something so easy to find on Stack Overflow?.

I add a new image for you to see what´s going on.

Comment: Well, your question didn't mention `setPalette` anywhere, how would I know that. I can't read your mind. Besides, what do you mean, do you mean that you can't set QWidget's background using the answer of that question?

Comment: Well. I just tell you, i asked because it's not trivial. Anyway, i never use that property (setAutoFillBackground) because of this phrase on the docs: "Warning: Use this property with caution in conjunction with Qt Style Sheets. When a widget has a style sheet with a valid background or a border-image, this property is automatically disabled."  Which is the case. So what you suggested is not completely correct. Though, thanks for that.

Comment: OK, could I suggest to edit your question and make it much more clear (and shorter, too) than it currently is. I haven't read your question in full, because it's too long. Also, add all those things from the comments to it. Editing will also bump it to the top btw, right now nobody's reading it but me.

Comment: ... Ok. I thought longer and with more explanations would be better...

Comment: Better to be concise. Remember, nobody's being paid to read your question, and right now, it would take 10 minutes of someone's time to read all of it. If it's 1-2 paragraphs, people will read it.

Comment: Done. Hope it´s better. :)

Comment: It should be half the size still IMO. Add only lines of code relevant to the problem, and the first sentence should be a summary of your question. Right now the actual question is in the middle of the post.

Comment: ..... itn´t it too much formal?. Come on, just 4 lines to read... are you waiting to answer me until i do it perfectly? is this any kind of torture? LOL... or because you want me to make me write the perfect question for the forum?... Im waiting for the answer in my job, people is waiting and this is taking too long. I think i´ll go to qt official forums, this is taking more than 6 days. Done.

Comment: 10 minutes. Took me 10 minutes instead of 5 days to get the answer. It was just one line. There are issues still... I understand , satuon, that things have to be ok here, but i think you are taking it too seriously for this question. i removed just 4 lines of code that is not useful... is that annoying for readers?...

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is to add this line of code.

```
paramPanelViewportWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
```

It still has some issues. Now it perfectly responds to transparent background and color background. But transparent shows what is behind the white panel containing it (the gray , blue background).

BUT this property DOESN´T work on WindowsXP. It´s a known bug of , at least, QT 4.7 which is the version i´m using.

When i resolve that last issue (which is additional to the original one) i´ll post it as an answer.

Hope it helps.

Comment: still waiting for a way to fix it. Sorry guys