# How to change QPushButton backround color without using CSS

Tags: python, pyqt

So far I am only able to customize the button text color:

```
button = QtGui.QPushButton()
palette = QtGui.QPalette(button.palette())
palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, QtGui.QColor('blue'))
button.setPalette(palette)
```

But how to change the button background color?

None of this will change the button background color:

```
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Foreground, QtGui.QColor('red'))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Button, QtGui.QColor('red'))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Light, QtGui.QColor('red'))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, QtGui.QColor('red'))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Dark, QtGui.QColor('red'))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Mid, QtGui.QColor('red'))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Text, QtGui.QColor('red'))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, QtGui.QColor('red'))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, QtGui.QColor('red'))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Base, QtGui.QColor('red'))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Background, QtGui.QColor('red'))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, QtGui.QColor('red'))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, QtGui.QColor('red'))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, QtGui.QColor('red'))
    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText, QtGui.QColor('red'))
```

Comment: how about this?  : `self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")`

Comment: This is CSS. The question is how to do the same without using it.

Comment: looks like `pallet.setColorGroup`? (http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qpalette.html#setColorGroup)

Comment: How to use `setColorGroup`? I can't find any example... :(

Comment: Not sure...there's also an old thread on a mailing list that gives an example of setting a button's background color: http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2006-February/012279.html

Comment: Another possibly related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655538/how-to-set-qwidget-background-color

Comment: Doesn's work with QPushButton or any other QButtons. I can't believe the most popular widget can't be customized with the colors without using CSS (which does more harm then good)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set the right "role" and append "setAutoFillBackground()":

```
button = QtGui.QPushButton()
palette = self.button.palette()
role = self.button.backgroundRole() #choose whatever you like
palette.setColor(role, QColor('red'))
button.setPalette(palette)
self.button.setAutoFillBackground(True)
```

Comment: You may also need to apply setFlat() depending on the theme (I did!). 
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685414/qt5-setting-background-color-to-qpushbutton-and-qcheckbox answers and comments

Answer (score 0):

Some QStyles, specifically Windows Vista, takes certain aspects of the gui from the operating system, so you can't change them directly with a QPalette.

You can query available QStyles with

```
QStyleFactory.keys()

['windowsvista', 'Windows', 'Fusion']
```

Change the qstyle to some other Style, with

```
app.setStyle("Fusion")
```

Now, it will respect a QPalette's

```
QPalette.Button
```